# How can I set the PHP error log on Windows?

Tags: php, error-logging

I'm having trouble enabling error logs in the *php.ini* file.

Whenever I uncomment this line where the log file is stored, the Wampserver icon stays orange.

```
;error_log = "D:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```

I've already enabled error logging:

```
log_errors = On
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may not be editing the correct *php.ini* file.

You can also set the *error_log* path with *[ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set)*.

Hmm, maybe you also should try it with file:://D:...

Comment: I'd prefer to put it on the php.ini file itself, most of what google returns is this ini_set